# SQL Server - Trying to figure out why I get a different result set when selecting from a CTE vs selecting from a temp table

Tags: sql-server

I have been working on updating a scalar function in SQL server. The original function utilized CTE's to select the initial data and then manipulate to achieve required results. In order to troubleshoot the bug that was occurring, I translated some of the CTE's to temp tables so that I can select and see the data through each step. I noticed though, I would get a different result set than when I would run the function as it was originally set up.

cte_filterDuplicates / @cte_filterDuplicates - This is the CTE/temp table that I am selecting from

```
  category|resultvalue
Blood Type|Abnormal
Blood Type|B
Blood Type|IMM
Blood Type|Neg
Blood Type|NL
Blood Type|NR
 Rh Factor|Pos
```

I then select from this into another CTE

```
,cte_format
as
(
    select
        (select top(1) resultvalue from cte_filterDuplicates as fd where fd.category = 'Blood Type') as bloodtype,
        (select top(1) resultvalue from cte_filterDuplicates as fd where fd.category = 'Rh Factor') as rh
)
```

I then select * from cte_format to see what I got

When making these tables as CTE's, my result set was:

```
bloodtype|rh
      Neg|Pos
```

However, when I do this where both of these are temp tables my result set differs:

```
bloodtype|rh
 Abnormal|Pos
```

This second result set is what I expected both to end up with but they don't.

Comment: The data is unordered unless you specify `order by`.

Comment: Yes, @JacobH is right. As long as you don't explicitly use `ORDER BY` the `(SELECT TOP(1) ...)` subqueries can and obviously will return any record, whatever the engine likes better in the current circumstances.

Comment: I figured the `(SELECT TOP(1) …)` would eliminate the need for an order by since I am only selecting 1 row. I am glad that I removed this part of the function.

Comment: You simply need to use `order by` with `top` if you are expecting ordered results. Otherwise, you cannot guarantee you will get `Abnormal` as the first row the engine returns. Using a temp table in a function might not be a good choice.

Comment: @JacobH I see what you are getting at, it makes sense. Thanks